# Does VF use API Calls when it is used to Update records?

Tags: api

I am reading this article - [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls.htm][1], which says when an Client Application updates/deletes etc it uses an API Call.

How about if I am doing any of the actions listed in that article through an Visualforce page? Does it still use API Calls?

Comment: Your link does not go anywhere but a list of items. As long as you are executing the classes and methods directly it will not. If your code still does a callout to the API then yes it will consume API calls into the org. So it depends on your implementation of "do it through visualforce"

Comment: Sorry this is the article - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls.htm

Comment: Those are docs for the SOAP API. Why use that from Visualforce? You can perform CRUD operations through an Apex controller or JS remoting and get the same functionality without using the API at all.

Comment: It said API Calls basic, so I figured that's where I could start :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the purely Visualforce APIs (@RemoteAction, apex:actionMethod, and apex:remoteObject), then no API calls are used. If you use general API calls, like webservice, @RestRequest, REST, SOAP, Tooling, Streaming, Metadata, or Bulk API endpoints, then the relevant API limits are consumed (Bulk, Streaming, and general API calls, as appropriate). Note that Visualforce APIs used through Sites still consume other limits, like CPU time, bandwidth, and page views.

Comment: what about js remoting and sforce object? I recall from some resource that sforce consumes API call.

Comment: @Mahmood RemoteAction is known as JavaScript remoting. It's free. The AJAX Toolkit uses SOAP, and so does cost API calls.